# sql case or not in

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

query1 table

```
case_no
1. 2761936
2. 2762090
3. 2762049
```

query_2 table

```
case_no  lawyer_id
2762090  215444 
2762090  118999
2762049  180444
```

I want to report on records where lawyer_id is > 100000 and lawyer_id >= 200000
If the lawyer_id is within that range, I dont want the case_no at all.Ideally the report should only show 2761936 and 2762049

I tried the following, but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT 
  q1.Case_no,q1.Form_no,q2.lawyer_id
FROM 
  [sample].[dbo].[Query1] Q1, 
  [sample].[dbo].[Query2] q2
where 
  q1.Case_no = q2.case_no
and q1.case_no not in(
  select 
    q1.case_no 
  from 
    [sample].[dbo].[Query2] q2
  where 
    q2.lawyer_id < 100000 and q2.lawyer_id >= 200000 )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is very confusing - can you edit it to clarify? You ask for `lawyer_id > 100000` and `lawyer_id >= 200000` (which means `lawyer_id >= 200000`), but your SQL says `lawyer_id < 100000` and `lawyer_id >= 200000`, which means none of them match (none can be `less than 100000 and greater than or equal to 200000`).

Comment: We assume this is a typo: _where lawyer_id is > 100000 and lawyer_id >= 200000_, and you really intended  _lawyer_id is > 100000 and lawyer_id <= 200000_

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be necessary to use a `NOT IN` subquery at all. The `WHERE` clause should be all you need with a simple `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT 
  q1.Case_no,
  q1.Form_no,
  q2.lawyer_id
FROM 
  [sample].[dbo].[Query1] Q1
  JOIN [sample].[dbo].[Query2] q2 ON q1.Case_no = q2.case_no
WHERE
  q2.lawyer_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a lawyer_id can never be both < 100000 and greater than 200000 you will never get any results.

You probably want:

```
q2.lawyer_id < 100000 OR q2.lawyer_id >= 200000
```

OR

```
NOT (q2.lawyer_id >= 100000 AND q2.lawyer_id <= 200000)
```

OR

```
NOT (q2.lawyer_id BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000)
```

I've reworked your SQL:

```
SELECT   A.CASE_NO,
         A.FORM_NO,
         B.LAWYER_ID
FROM     [sample].[dbo].[Query1] A,
         [sample].[dbo].[Query2] B
WHERE    A.CASE_NO = B.CASE_NO
AND      NOT (B.LAWYER_ID BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000)
```

Answer (score 1):

From your expected results I infer that you want:

- all cases
- MINUS cases for which there exists at least one lawyer whose id is less than 100000
- MINUS cases for which there exists at least one lawyer whose id is greater than or equal to 200000.

In which case:

```
WITH query1
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (2761936), 
                     (2762090), 
                     (2762049)
             ) AS T (case_no)
     ),
     query2
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES (2762090, 215444),
                     (2762090, 118999),
                     (2762049, 180444)
             ) AS T (case_no, lawyer_id)
     )

SELECT case_no 
  FROM query1 -- sample.dbo.query1
EXCEPT
SELECT case_no 
  FROM query2 -- sample.dbo.query2
 WHERE lawyer_id < 100000 
EXCEPT
SELECT case_no 
  FROM query2 -- sample.dbo.query2
 WHERE lawyer_id >= 200000;
```

Perhaps you'd then want to refactor the query e.g.

```
SELECT case_no 
  FROM query1 -- sample.dbo.query1
EXCEPT
SELECT case_no 
  FROM query2 -- sample.dbo.query2
 WHERE ( lawyer_id < 100000 
         OR lawyer_id >= 200000 );
```